# custom keyboard layouts crash the applications

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout

I want to test [**Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=102134). (The goal is to switch between two layouts that I use often with a hotkey and have additional layouts). I load the existing layout "US", swap the keys <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> , generate and run the setup package. The custom layout is added to the language "English (United States)". Then I open Notepad and try to switch to the custom layout by clicking on it in the language bar. When I click on the layout the taskbar restarts and there are messages like this in the Windows Applications log:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.22621.1485, time stamp: 0x170d6771
Faulting module name: InputSwitch.dll, version: 10.0.22621.900, time stamp: 0xaf886d1e
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000003d477
Faulting process id: 0x0x66B8
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D979C50832CE2B
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\InputSwitch.dll
Report Id: dafc77c3-0780-49a5-97e6-54ea0ed3a584
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" Guid="{a0e9b465-b939-57d7-b27d-95d8e925ff57}" /> 
  <EventID>1000</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-04-28T11:33:47.8592447Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>2353</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="9744" ThreadID="17924" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>basinpad</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-70058815-1429380656-3497993355-1001" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="AppName">explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppVersion">10.0.22621.1485</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppTimeStamp">170d6771</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleName">InputSwitch.dll</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleVersion">10.0.22621.900</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleTimeStamp">af886d1e</Data> 
  <Data Name="ExceptionCode">c0000409</Data> 
  <Data Name="FaultingOffset">000000000003d477</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x66b8</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessCreationTime">0x1d979c50832ce2b</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppPath">C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModulePath">C:\Windows\System32\InputSwitch.dll</Data> 
  <Data Name="IntegratorReportId">dafc77c3-0780-49a5-97e6-54ea0ed3a584</Data> 
  <Data Name="PackageFullName" /> 
  <Data Name="PackageRelativeAppId" /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Keyboard Creator is very old now.

> Before we start, a word of warning: the Microsoft Keyboard Layout
> Creator app is nearly a decade old. It still works perfectly and runs
> on Windows 10, but occasionally you might encounter a bug.

[Keyboard Creator](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-custom-keyboard-layout-windows/#:%7E:text=Before%20we%20start%2C%20a%20word%20of%20warning%3A%20the,10%2C%20but%20occasionally%20you%20might%20encounter%20a%20bug.)

I suggest you do not use it on Windows 11.

Take a look at Microsoft Power Toys (Microsoft Store) instead as it has keyboard settings that work on Windows 11.